# Running shell scripts on Jailbroken Kindle

Tags: linux, kindle

I'm trying to do something similar to [Matthew Petroff's weather display](https://mpetroff.net/2012/09/kindle-weather-display/) on a Kindle 4. I have managed to jailbreak the kindle and ssh into it. Now, however, I'm wondering what the best way to run [the shell scripts that Petroff shows on the GitHub page](https://github.com/mpetroff/kindle-weather-display/tree/master/kindle) is. He mentions that he used Kite, which sounds like it would be great, but I gather that Kite is only for Kindle 3s or earlier.

So in other words my question is this: is there a way to let me select "weather script" on my Kindle 4 and have it show the weather image (and periodically refresh it), but otherwise function as a normal Kindle?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

While Kite should also work on the Kindle 4 (Petroff used one, too), I recommend using the more modern KUAL (Kindle Unified Application Launcher) instead.

Download and installation instructions can be found here: https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=203326

I haven't found a documentation for KUAL anywhere but it's open source and you can also look at one of the already made applications for it.